# слияние веток с хронологией

Tags: git, git-rebase

Есть такая ситуация: две *orphan* ветки имеют свою историю, файлы не пересекаются (возможно, имена папок могут совпасть). **Хотелось бы из двух сделать одну, но с сохранением хронологии коммитов**. Ниже приведены две схемы.

```
A - B - - - - - C < master

  D - E - F - G   < main
```

Желаемый результат:

```
A - D - B - E - F - G - C < master
```

Я погуглил немного и `git merge` или `git rebase` мне не поможет в простых случаях. Делать `git cherry-pick` на каждый коммит не хочется, так как история коммитов, вообще-то, больше, чем на схеме и ручная работа займёт много времени.

Могу предположить, что существуют какие-то скрипты или *git-filter-repo* что-то такое умеет, но у последнего как-то сложно с документацией. Или всё же встроенные команды типа `git rebase` могут сделать слияние.

Comment: Если `git cherry-pick` работает без конфликтов, то наверное проще написать скрипт. Я сомневаюсь что есть готовые, задачка уж больно странная и нестандартная.

Comment: с помощью команды `log` получаете список вида "дата хэш", сортируете по дате, проходитесь в цикле командой `cherry-pick`. зачем тут ещё что-то (скорее всего несуществующее в природе) искать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, накидал небольшой скрипт на Python с использованием GitPython. Дальше уже можно через *git-filter-repo* прогнать, чтобы сопоставить дату автора и коммита.

```py
import git

repo = git.Repo("../repo")
commits = []
branches = repo.heads
for branch in branches:
  commits += list(repo.iter_commits(branch))
commits.sort(key = lambda x: x.authored_date)
repo.create_head("temp", commit = commits[0])
repo.git.checkout("temp")
commits.pop(0) # чтобы два раза не повторять initial commit
for commit in commits:
  print(commit.authored_datetime, commit.hexsha)
  repo.git.cherry_pick(commit.hexsha)
```

Если есть предложения к улучшению всегда готов принять.